# How to get JSON array inside JSON array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, chat

I have JSON response with messages from url(server).

```html
{
  "response": [
    79457,
    {
      "mid": 321,
      "date": 123,
      "out": 1,
      "uid": 984,
      "read_state": 1,
      "title": " ... ",
      "body": "message",
      "fwd_messages": [
        {
          "uid": 981,
          "date": 152,
          "body": "forwarded messages 1",
          "fwd_messages": [
            {
              "uid": 654,
              "date": 156,
              "body": "1"
            },
            {
              "uid": 174,
              "date": 158,
              "body": "2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "uid": 949,
          "date": 651,
          "body": "forwarded messages 2",
          "fwd_messages": [
            {
              "uid": 694,
              "date": 320,
              "body": "32",
              "fwd_messages": [
                {
                  "uid": 152,
                  "date": 111,
                  "body": "1",
                  "fwd_messages": [
                    {
                      "uid": 151,
                      "date": 112,
                      "body": "8"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "uid": 542,
                  "date": 315,
                  "body": "2",
                  "fwd_messages": [
                    {
                      "uid": 129,
                      "date": 514,
                      "body": "1",
                      "fwd_messages": [
                        {
                          "uid": 635,
                          "date": 225,
                          "body": "8"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "uid": 123,
              "date": 650,
              "body": "",
              "fwd_messages": [
                {
                  "uid": 154,
                  "date": 122,
                  "body": "1"
                },
                {
                  "uid": 547,
                  "date": 510,
                  "body": "2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Some messages can have forwarded messages in arrays "fwd_messages" and forwarded messages can be inside another forwarded messages like this:

```html
          "uid": 949,
          "date": 651,
          "body": "forwarded messages 2",
          "fwd_messages": [
            {
              "uid": 694,
              "date": 320,
              "body": "32",
              "fwd_messages": [
                {
                  "uid": 152,
                  "date": 111,
                  "body": "1",
                  "fwd_messages": [
                    {
                      "uid": 151,
                      "date": 112,
                      "body": "8"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "uid": 542,
                  "date": 315,
                  "body": "2",
                  "fwd_messages": [
                    {
                      "uid": 129,
                      "date": 514,
                      "body": "1",
                      "fwd_messages": [
                        {
                          "uid": 635,
                          "date": 225,
                          "body": "8"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "uid": 123,
              "date": 650,
              "body": "",
              "fwd_messages": [
                {
                  "uid": 154,
                  "date": 122,
                  "body": "1"
                },
                {
                  "uid": 547,
                  "date": 510,
                  "body": "2"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

I have a simple message class called Message

```html
public class Message
{
    public int user_id;
    public int date;
    public String body;
    public List<FwdMessages> fwdMessages;

    public Message (int user_id, int date, String body, List<FwdMessages> fwdMessages) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.date = date;
        this.body = body;
        this.fwdMessages = fwdMessages;
    }
}
```

And Forwarded Messages class

```html
public class FwdMessages {
    public int user_id;
    public int date;
    public String body;
    public List<FwdMessages> fwdMessages;

}
```

So how can I get this forwarded messages inside another forwarded messages and put them into a list? And it should be noted that one fwd messages object is from another. Sorry of my English :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you there I didn't test this code on editor but you can have idea from this code how it works.

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONOBject(myString);
if(mainObj != null){
    JSONArray list = mainObj.getJSONArray("prodCat_list");
    if(list != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length();i++){
            JSONObject elem = list.getJSONObject(i);
            if(elem != null){
                JSONArray prods = elem.getJSONArray("prods");
                if(prods != null){
                    for(int j = 0; j < prods.length();j++){
                        JSONObject innerElem = prods.getJSONObject(j);
                        if(innerElem != null){
                            int cat_id = innerELem.getInt("cat_id");
                            int pos = innerElem.getInt("position");
                            String sku = innerElem.getString("sku");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size of that array? The "fwd_messages" array can consists either of 1 or 5 forwarded messages inside

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Gson`, which is available from Maven directories, you can initialize a variable from the response you just got, like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Message m = gson.fromJson(response, Message.class);
```

From there, a get will be enough. 
There's another option, which involves a little more work, but it works fine also. It consists of making a `JSONObject` from a JSON response from the server, and calling a get to that `JSONObject`, it would look like this:

```
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = new JSONObject(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And then, you can call another get, but from `obj`, like this:

```
JSONObject response = obj.getJSONObject("response");
JSONArray<FwdMessages> array = response.getJSONArray("fwd_messages");
```

And from there, you will be just 1 get away from getting the object or attribute you're looking for.